# Multiple queries doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I try to execute 3 queries one after one but it only execute 2 and don't get any errors...
It only echo the first one and then nothing and when look in to the table through phpMyAdmin I see that didn't inserted any row( last query).

```
$queryGetOpis = $con->query('SELECT numar FROM Opis ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1');
$data = $queryGetOpis->fetch_assoc();
$numar = intval($data["numar"])+1;

echo '<h2>Numarul este ' . $numar . '</h2>';

if ($queryUpdateOpis = $con->prepare('UPDATE Opis SET numar=' . $numar . ' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1'))
{
    $queryUpdateOpis->execute();
    $queryUpdateOpis->close();
}
else echo "Eroare ".$con->error;

if ($queryInsertUser = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO Opis(numar,user,data) VALUES(' . $numar . ', "' . $_COOKIE[LOGIN_COOKIE] . '", "' . date("dmYHi") . '")'))
{
    $queryInsertUser->execute();
    $queryInsertUser->close();
}
else echo "Eroare ".$con->error;
```

Comment: You're missing the point of using prepared statements by putting your values right in your query.

Comment: Print out the SQL queries and run it manually using phpMyAdmin or similar. Does it work?

Comment: That second one is interesting, do you want to update some random row?

Comment: @JohnConde It's my style and don't think is the error.

Comment: @jeroen I want to update first row and works.
Edited the query to: 'UPDATE Opis SET numar=' . $numar . ' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1'

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes. Means same to date in romanian.